# ExpandableListAdapter: Notifying calling code of changes

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

I have an Activity that sets an ExpandableListAdapter for an ExpandableListView.

I would like the adapter to notify the Activity when its underlying data changes.  How is this possible?

Thanks,
wTs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reload you list view, try to call the notifyDataSetChanged() method inside of your adapter.